# chart.js How to show last column’s value on y axios?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[chart1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufZRk.png)

This is my chart,i want show value,look like:

[chart2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq1gt.png)

Please tell me,is this possible?

Comment: **YES !!** ­­­­­­­

Comment: @ℊααnd solved,thx

Answer (score 0):

i find chart.ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY)

it works